Can AVX-512 be used to calculate the multiplication of two 256-bit Integers on a 64 bit computer in C++? Whether using Assembly Language or not
Regarding arbitrary precision arithmetic: Can AVX-512 be used to calculate the multiplication of two 256-bit Integers on a 64-bit computer in C++?
Is there an intrinsic Integer data type of 512 bits for the result, in a C++ compiler, that makes it possible?
If its not possible, can it be done in Assembly language? If so, can this Assembly Language routine be called from a C++ program? Could a 512-bit result from an Assembly Language routine be utilised by 64-bit Integer data types without using a String?

You can use the Intel Intrinsics to access all AVX512 instructions from C/C++. However, AVX does not have extended multiplication. The best you can get is vectorized signed 64 bit multiplication that returns the low 64 bit of the result for up to 8 independent multiplications (_mm512_mullo_epi64) or 8 x 32 bit multiplications with full 64 bit results (_mm512_mul_epi32 for signed, _mm512_mul_epu32 for unsigned).

512 refers to the maximum amount of data that can be processed at once but each element in the 512 bit block is still at most 64 bits https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#

Technically yes, but not with a single instruction with a simple storage format.  See Can long integer routines benefit from SSE? - speedups are possible with storage formats that leave some bits unused in each 64-bit limb, allowing AVX-512IFMA or bithacks to use the mantissa part of an FMA (like Prime95 or y-Cruncher does.)

Yes and no.
No, AVX-512 doesn't have an instruction to multiply two 256-bit operands to get a 512-bit result. The largest operands you can multiply are 64 bits apiece, to get a 128-bit result.
So, to multiply 256-bit operands, you do a bit like grade-school multiplication. Except that you want to treat a 256-bit number as basically a 4-digit number in base 264. So, you have something like:
          D  C  B  A
          H  G  F  E
--------------------
         ED EC EB EA
      FD FC FB FA 0
   GD GC GB GA 0  0
HD HC HB HA 0  0  0
--------------------

[where HD means H*D, GB means G*B, and so on.]
So just like we did in grade-school, we multiply each digit of the one by each digit of the other, carry the upper digit of each to the next column, and add all the partial products together to get a final result.
The difference is that instead of each being a digit from 0 to 9, in this case each digit goes from 0 to 264-1.
But yes, since you have to carry out identical operations on each of multiple operands, it's perfectly reasonable to carry them out in parallel using vector instructions. But that's just doing a bunch of 64-bit multiplications in parallel, not working with any individual operand that's any bigger than 64 bits1.
If you're working with really big numbers (e.g., millions of digits or more) there are better multiplication methods, such as Karatsuba multiplication and Schönhage-Strassen multiplication -- but 512 bits is almost certainly too small to benefit noticeably from things like that.


I should add, however, that although the idea of vectored execution is valid, it may be a lot of work for little or no gain, so unless you're doing a lot of these in a tight loop, it's open to a lot of question whether it'll be worthwhile.


Nice answer. But… correct me if I'm wrong: You would need 64 bit multiplication that generates 128 bit results for this, right? Back to the grade-school example, you need single digit multiplications that can result in 2 digit results (9x9 = 81, etc.). Since we don't have that in AVX, we need to do vectorized 32 bit multiplications that give 64 bit results. And when we do the additions, we have to worry about the carry bits.

@Homer512: Yes, that's correct. If you're dealing with something that can't generate the double-sized result, you'd typically start by breaking it up into 32-bit chunks, so individual results would fit into 64-bit registers (or more generally, into have the size of a register, so each result will fit in a register).

You would need a lot of shuffling and addition with carry, which likely does not make it worth the effort, if you only do a single 256x256 product. If you have really big products and you have AVX512IFMA52, it may be worth looking into splitting the number into 52bit limbs (vpmadd52luq and vpmadd52huq have better throughput and the final carry-addition can be done at the very end).
